# Laravel voyager not showing full side menu

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am very new to laravel. After installing voyager (php artisan voyager:install) and migrating the database (php artisan migrate), the full menu of voyager is not shown (see attached)
[image: screenshot voyager]

Any advice/indication will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the fact that I was calling the admin page of voyager using https. When I troied with http the dashboard menu was shown.